# AddEventListener при событии keyup вызывает абсолютно другую функцию

Tags: javascript

Решил сделать для себя таймер ибо скачивать не хочется в веб странице.

Пауза и старт работали по кнопкам и по пробелу.

Я добавил новую кнопку `Reset`, а с ней и функцию. После ее использования она вызывается по нажатию на пробел. По логике я вызываю
ее только по нажатию кнопки.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
        if(e.code == "Space"){
            if(run){
                run = false;
            }else{
                run = true;
                game()
            }
        }
    })
```

под `game` я имею ввиду запуск таймера.

Comment: Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. То есть при нажатии пробела происходит пауза.  В любом другом случае, при нажатии любой кнопки, происходит запуск функции. Опишите подробнее какого результата хотите добиться?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на самом деле я дебил и не так понял 
когда я нажимал на кнопку ресет на ней оставался фокус и с помощью пробела она нажималась, если кому поможет буду рад

как исправить:

```
<button id="reset" onclick = "this.blur(); reset()">RESET</button>
```